# Unexpected behavior of css when using :hover, what is happening?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I found a problem with this `:hover` effect, that I have never seen before.
When I `:hover` on the div "box".. this changes a section of the background...

Thanks !

**CSS FOR SECTIONS**

```
.first { background:#fff; width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;}     

.second {background-image:url(../images/body/1.jpg); background-attachment:fixed;width:100%; height:auto; position:relative; display:inline-block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="span4 one">
    <i class=" icon-4x icon-beaker">
    </i>
    <h2>
        Awesome
    </h2>
    <p>
        Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam
        id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta
        ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel
        scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
    </p>
    <button type="submit">
        shown more
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS FOR BOXES**

```
 .boxes .span4{text-align:center; padding:10px 0; display:inline;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
       -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
         -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
        -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
            transition: all 300ms linear;}

==>.boxes .span4:hover {background: rgba(51,153,255,0.1);}<===
```

Comment: what "box" div? there is no mention of "box" anywhere in your html snippet. as for css changing on hover, that's easy enough to do with `:hover`.

Comment: on hover it turn opacity on, whats the problem?

Comment: i created a demo for better understanding http://jsfiddle.net/nbBj4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `background-attachment: fixed;` doesn't line translations (it basically changes the fixed position of the background image, depending on the elements above it that are translating on the Y axis)